# Entity Framework 6.0 inheritance collection mapping

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm learning about EF Code First, but I got a problem.
I have master and detail abstract classes, during data binding to UI controls I receive an exception.

In the WPF master/detail form for online courses I have a DataGrid(Detail) for students.
When I try to add a line to the `DataGrid` this exception is thrown

> Cannot create an instance of NameSpace.student  because it is an abstract class.

So how can I map `Students` collection as `OnlineStudents` in onlineCourse and `OfflineStudents` in offlineCourse?

```
public abstract class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public virtual System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    }

    public class OnlineCouse : Course
    {
        public string URI { get; set; }
    }

    public class OnlineStudent : Student
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    class InstContext : DbContext
    {

        public InstContext()
            : base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Course> Course{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Student{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<InstContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<InstContext>());



            modelBuilder.Entity<OnlineCouse>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("OnlineCourse");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<OnlineStudent>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("OnlineStudent");
            });
        }
    }
```

the following is Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="onlineCourseViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type XData:OnlineCourse}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="onlineCourseStudentsViewSource" Source="{Binding Students, Source={StaticResource gSVoucherViewSource}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource onlineCourseViewSource}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Id:"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="idTextBox"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="Email:"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="EmailTextBox"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="studentsDataGrid"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource onlineCourseStudentsViewSource}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="In Area" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>         
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The problem is:
If I have an abstract master class which has an abstract child class collection, how do I override this in derived master class to have derived Child collection?

Comment: Could post sample of code where you "try to add a line to datagrid"?

Comment: code added, thanks for your response

Comment: i believe this `public DbSet<Course> Course{ get; set; }` would be invalid, you can not use an abstract class here.

Comment: You need to define what type of student you want to fetch using [`.OfType<>() `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A side note: Use `ICollection<Student>` instead of `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Student>`  as data type of `Course.Students`.

Comment: @seaBizkit this part is working ok as this tutorial suggests https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: @adnan Umer Would you please give me code example because i tried but my trial failed

Comment: @HaithamKhttab try `DbContext.Student.OfType<OnlineStudent>()`